# Create a frequency table in R with square bracket in left interval and round bracket in right

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

In the given code:

```
table(cut(rpois(1000, 50), seq(0, 100, by = 10)))
```

the result is such that `L < x <= U`. I would like the result to be `L <= x < U`. This is required for entire for all. I have tried including `include.lowest` and `include.highest` but it doesn't work or I might be applying it incorrectly. Please help. I would appreciate if the code is simple using `base`/`stats` only. Else also is fine.

Comment: `cut(..., right = FALSE)`